# Tabular missing border and not fitting to text

Tags: tables, spacing

i'm very new to LaTeX,

i'm trying to do a basic tabular, however the borders disappear when i put too much text in the cases, and the bottom border is missing. Plus, the tabular is too small and not really readable so i would like to change the row height.
Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}

\hline
Donnée &  Figure & Propriété & Conclusion \\
\hline
$(d_{1})$ et $(d_{2})$ sont
symétriques
\\ par rapport
au point K.
 &  ? & Si ... alors ... & ....
 \\
\hline
... et ... sont ... par  rapport à Y & ? & Si ... alors ... & $\widehat{ABC} = \widehat{EFG}$ \\

\hline  

Les cercles
$(C_{1})$ de rayon $r_{1}$ et
$(C_{2})$ de rayon $r_{2}$
\\sont symétriques
par rapport à T.  
& ? & Si ........ alors .... & $r_{1} =$ ...\\



\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Here's the result

[image]

Can you help me please ?

Comment: The bottom border is missing because there is no `\hline` .

Comment: To make the table fit into the textwidth I'd use `tabularx` and its `X` type column instead of manual linebreaks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the table fit into the textwidt, I removed all manual linebreaks in the first column and used `tabularx` instead. I have defined a new, left aligned column type that automatically fills the remaining space to the left margin. In the first example, I have also added the missing `\hline` at the bottom of the table and added the `cellspace` package to prevent the `\widehat` from overlapping with the horizontal line. I have also added a second example in which I removed all vertical lines and replaced the `\hline` commands with the horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{\tabcolsep}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\cellspacetoplimit}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X, L}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|S{L}|Sc|Sc|Sc|}
\hline
Donnée &  Figure & Propriété & Conclusion \\
\hline
$(d_{1})$ et $(d_{2})$ sont
symétriques
 par rapport
au point K.
 &  ? & Si ... alors ... & ....
 \\
\hline
... et ... sont ... par  rapport à Y & ? & Si ... alors ... & $\widehat{ABC} = \widehat{EFG}$ \\

\hline  

Les cercles
$(C_{1})$ de rayon $r_{1}$ et
$(C_{2})$ de rayon $r_{2}$
sont symétriques
par rapport à T.  
& ? & Si ........ alors .... & $r_{1} =$ ...\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Lccc}
\toprule
Donnée &  Figure & Propriété & Conclusion \\
\midrule
$(d_{1})$ et $(d_{2})$ sont
symétriques
 par rapport
au point K.
 &  ? & Si ... alors ... & ....
 \\
... et ... sont ... par  rapport à Y & ? & Si ... alors ... & $\widehat{ABC} = \widehat{EFG}$ \\
Les cercles
$(C_{1})$ de rayon $r_{1}$ et
$(C_{2})$ de rayon $r_{2}$
sont symétriques
par rapport à T.  
& ? & Si ........ alors .... & $r_{1} =$ ...\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it really helped me understand how it works.I appreciate